# Getting an Error (gob: unknown type id or corrupted data) when trying to decode a blob using gob.Decoder()

Tags: go, gob

I'm trying to to send an encoded blob to a list of local peers(a client code listening at multiple ports on a local machine), at the peers when i decode the blob for some peers it works but for some it doesn't and displays an error(gob: unknown type id or corrupted data), how can i solve this ?

```
//My blob struct
type packet struct {
    Nodes []a1.Node
    Ledger *a1.Block
    ActionType string
}


//Encoding Part
    for i:=1; i<len(ConnectedNodes);i++{
        var blob packet
        blob.Ledger = Ledger
        blob.ActionType = "AddBlock"
        blob.Nodes = []a1.Node{}
        conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost"+":"+ConnectedNodes[i].Port)
        if err != nil {
            // handle error
            fmt.Println("Error At Client In Making A Connection (sending New Block to client "+ ConnectedNodes[i].Name +")")
        }
        //sending request type to client
        _, _ = conn.Write([]byte("newblock add "))
        //sending data to the client node
        //gob.Register(blob)
        encoder := gob.NewEncoder(conn)
        error := encoder.Encode(blob)
        if error != nil {
            log.Fatal(error)
        }
    }

//Decoding Part running on another peer
//adds new block to the Ledger

//Recieving incoming data
    recvdSlice := make([]byte, 256)
    conn.Read(recvdSlice)
    RecievedData := string(recvdSlice)
    finalData := strings.Split(RecievedData, " ")

    if finalData[0] == "newblock"{
        var blob packet
        decoder := gob.NewDecoder(conn)
        err := decoder.Decode(&blob)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error at decoding New Block on client!")
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(Ledger.Hash)
        fmt.Println(blob.Ledger.Hash)
        if(bytes.Compare(Ledger.Hash, blob.Ledger.Hash)) == 0 {
            fmt.Println("Ledger is already updated !")
        }else{
            fmt.Println("New Block Added !")
            Ledger = blob.Ledger
        }
        a1.ListBlocks(Ledger)
        //SendingNewBlockToConnectedNodes()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sender writes 13 bytes before encoding gob (`"newblock add "`).

If the receiver does not read these 13 bytes before decoding the gob, then the decoder will be out of sync with the data stream and report an error.

The connection Read method returns when data is available, the slice is filled or there is an error reading the connection. Ignoring errors, the call to Read on the connection will read between 1 and len(recvdSlice) bytes from the connection. There's no guarantee that 13 bytes of data is read, but it happens frequently in practice because of timing.

Fix by reading just the prefix before decoding the gob.  One way is to delimit the prefix with a newline.

Change the sender code to:

```
 _, _ = conn.Write([]byte("newblock add \n"))
```

Change the receiver code to:

```
 br := bufio.NewReader(conn)
 receivedData, err := br.ReadString('\n')
 if err != nil {
     // handle error
 }
 finalData := strings.Split(receivedData, " ")

 if finalData[0] == "newblock"{
    var blob packet
    decoder := gob.NewDecoder(br) // <-- decode from the buffered reader
    err := decoder.Decode(&blob)
```

Another fix is to use the gob codec for the prefix.  Change the sender to:

```
    encoder := gob.NewEncoder(conn)
    if err := encoder.Encode("newblock add "); err != nil {
        // handle error
    }
    if err := encoder.Encode(blob); err != nil {
        // handle error
    }
```

Change the receiver to:

```
decoder := gob.NewDecoder(conn)
var receivedData string
if err := decoder.Decode(&receivedData); err != nil {
     // handle error
}
finalData := strings.Split(receivedData, " ")

if finalData[0] == "newblock"{
    var blob packet
    err := decoder.Decode(&blob)
```

Comment: it worked, thank you. Can you elaborate a little bit on why the number of bytes sent and received must be equal ?

Comment: ah i get it for real now(i should not have deleted my previous comment), when i was trying to read the []byte(string) i was also reading a chunk of decoded blob as well which corrupted the blob or the decoder didn't know what type it was.

Comment: The call to Read reads up between 1 and 256 bytes of data from the connection. If the amount of data read is less than 13 bytes, then the decoder starts reading prefix data and errors out.  If the amount of data read is greater than 13 bytes, the the decoder starts reading mid gob an errors out.

Comment: makes sense, i'm new to go and network programming it was an obvious mistake but i just couldn't get my head around it anyway i really appreciate your help, have a good one.